# How to show condition for travelling wave solution to Fisher's equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I don't know how to to do this one part of a problem from my (non-PDE) math course. It's about the Fisher's equation. I've never encountered it before.

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} = D \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2} + ap(1-p) $$

How do I **(1)** show that the travelling wave solutions to this ($S(z)=p(x,t)$, where $z=x-vt$) must satisfy:

$$\frac{dP}{dz} = S$$
$$\frac{dS}{dz} = -\frac{a}{D} P(1-P) - \frac{v}{D}S$$

and **(2)** deduce the minimum travelling speed.

Thanks.

Comment: For $1)$ Substitute $S(x - vt) = S(z) $ into your PDE. You should get the ODE

$$-v S' = D S'' + a S (1 - S)$$

where $S' = dS/dz$. Then set $S' = P \implies S'' = P' = \dots$ which gives you a system of ODEs. We can go through $2)$ once you understand part $1)$.

Comment: @Mattos Oops I just noticed that I made a typo. It was supposed to be  $P(z) = p(x, t)$... Does this change anything?

Comment: No it doesn't. You're just using a particular variable $P$ to name your function, nothing more. Call the function what ever variable you would like.

Comment: @Mattos yay I got it! Thanks. I let $P$ be a solution and then took the appropriate partial derivatives (using chain rule) to substitute into the given equation. Then I let $S=P'$ (which is the first condition.) Then I rearranged the equation and to isolate $\frac{d^2 P}{dz^2}$ which is also equal to $S'$ and this turned out to be the second condition. But how do I go from this to minimum speed. Does this have to do with $D$?

Comment: I'm glad you managed to get it. For part $2)$, you need to analyse your ODE system. **Hint:** What can you say about the critical points and eigenvalues of the Jacobian of your system?

Comment: @Mattos I get two steady states. One's a saddle (because both eigenvalues are real and of opposite signs) and the other is a stable node (because both eigenvalues are real and positive).

Comment: I think you mean the stable node has eigenvalues that are real and _negative_. An _unstable_ node has eigenvalues that are positive.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. It's a stable node because it has real and negative eigenvalues. But this is assuming that the part under the square root, when solving eigenvalues for both points, is positive, right? So do I just isolate $v$ in both radicands and take the lower one as the minimum value possible? Which I think would be $v > \sqrt{D^2 - 4aD}$

Comment: Correction: It would just be $v > 2\sqrt{aD}$

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right. The reason why we don't examine the saddle node (in case you were wondering) is because it doesn't provide a realistic solution for a biological system. And your solution $v > 2 \sqrt{aD}$ is the minimum wave speed. Well done. You may want to also write up your solution in your OP or as a new answer, so that others may see your working for future reference. And (+1) on your post from me for working through the problem yourself.

Comment: @Mattos Thank you for helping me! I tried to (+1) your comments but it won't let me. I think it's because I don't have enough rep. I'll try to write up my solution later and post it.

Comment: It's all good, upvoting a comment doesn't do anything for the person who commented except let them now what they have posted is helpful. And I'm happy to help.